# Mount NFS share on host to docker container using -v or --mount

Tags: linux, docker, nfs

I am trying to bind the docker container during its start with a directory mounted from NFS on the docker host machine. I can view the contents of the directory on the host machine where I mounted NFS share. I unable to view the contents of the directory inside the running container (errors "ls: cannot access ... Permission denied). I have double checked the user and group permissions and they all look correct.

Example:

```
mount 10.1.0.0:/test /mnt/test
```

Once the  directory is mounted, its available on */mnt/test* on the docker host machine. I can list the contents of the directory.

Now I launch the docker container as

```
docker run -v /mnt/test:/mnt/test -it myImage bash
```

When I now list the contents of the path *ls -l /mnt/test*, it errors
*ls: cannot access ... Permission denied*

Comment: You need to check the uid/gid of the user inside the container. It probably maps to a user of the host system that doesn't have access to /mnt/test

Comment: I have checked that and it matches with container uid and gid that should have access.

Comment: Sounds like an idmapping issue with user namespaces, Maybe [this](https://whyistheinternetbroken.wordpress.com/2018/08/16/securing-nfs-mounts-in-a-docker-container/) will help.